# record.data.Id is undefined in sencha touch on android os 4.0.3

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have design sencha Touch 2  app which works in android o.s 2.3.6 but having some issue in android o.s 4.0.3
In android o.s 4.0.3 on click on list Item record.data.Id is undefined.
But for android o.s 2.3.6 I am getting value for record.data.Id.
Rest of the thing works fine.

Thanks

Comment: are you using Phonegap?